# How to select from a set of possible values in minikanren / clojure-core.logic?

Tags: clojure, scheme, clojure-core.logic, minikanren

How do I express the constraint that `n` variables take different values from a set of `n` values?

For example, maybe I want to search for the expression of the form

```
(op1 a (op2 b c))
```

with the largest value, when a, b and c should 1, 2 and 3 (in some order) while op1 and op2 can each be anything from `* + - / exp`?

I can see how to make `a` have a value from `1 2 3` (by using `conde` for example).  And the same for `b` and `c`.  But then how do I exclude equality?  Do I need to loop over all combinations and explicitly exclude them?

Obviously I can do the exclusion "by hand", but I am wondering if there is a better (more efficient) way, or a support library that includes things like this (I have a little more experience with linear programming libs and typically they have a bunch of helper functions that address these kinds of common cases).

And generalising it to the case where some values can appear a certain number of times seems like it's going to be a drag...

And now I think about it, how do I search for a maximum?  Is there a good book or set of notes on this?!

[I'm using clojure but my understanding is that clojure-core.logic and minikanren are pretty much identical]

**Update**: anyone reading this question looking for a good introduction, check out the [Alvis paper](http://www.schemeworkshop.org/2011/papers/Alvis2011.pdf) I mention below in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(run* [q] 
  (fresh [a b c]
    (== q [a b c])
    (fresh [x y z]
      (rembero a '(* + / - exp) x)
      (rembero b x y)
      (rembero c y z))))
```

Comment: Aha.  So clojure-core includes cKaren extensions - http://www.schemeworkshop.org/2011/papers/Alvis2011.pdf (I should read docs more carefully).  Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that is a cKanren extension? rembero is a relation defined in TRS, which was recently added to core.logic for convenience.

Comment: https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/ (which mentions cKanren) and http://www.schemeworkshop.org/2011/papers/Alvis2011.pdf (which describes cKanren and mentions rembero); if that's not right, is there some other doc i am missing?

Comment: ok, now i've read the paper, you're right, it refers to trs.  for anyone else reading this, ckanren does seem to be in clojure-core.logic, but some things have been renamed.  all-difffd is differfd, for example.